# Write custom SQL query for multiple counts

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, logic

I have the table in MySQL, containing `group_name` and `username`, like this:

```
ID|group_name|username
----------------------
1 |    A     | user1
----------------------
2 |    B     | user2
----------------------
3 |    C     | user1

...
```

And I have some logical expression that looks like this:

```
(A & B) || C
```

Which means, that if I'm searching by some user, this user should be in both groups A and B, or in C.

I have to check users with custom expressions in Laravel, and my query will look like this:

```
return DB::table('assigned_groups')->where($expression)->where('username', $username)->count();
```

Where `$expression` is my logical expression written in raw SQL, I guess. And I have to check whether some `$username` can be found assigned to needed groups at least once.

For now I just have a piece of pseudocode for $expression like this:

```
select count(*)
having (
    (count(select(*) where group_name = A) > 0 
    and count(select(*) where group_name = B) > 0)
    or count(select(*) where group_name = C) > 0
)
```

**How do I write this expression correctly?** How should I change my Laravel query and `$expression` itself?

UPD: now my SQL looks like this, and it's almost something

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `assigned_groups`
where username = 'user1'
having (
    (count(case group_name when 'A' then 1 else null end) > 0 
    and count(case group_name when 'B' then 1 else null end) > 0)
    or count(case group_name when 'C' then 1 else null end) > 0
)
```

Comment: You can always use DB::select if you have issues implementing the sql expression in laravel. Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your raw expression using `havingRaw`

```
DB::table('assigned_groups')
->where('username', $username)
->havingRaw("(count(case group_name when 'A' then 1 else null end) > 0 
    and count(case group_name when 'B' then 1 else null end) > 0)
    or count(case group_name when 'C' then 1 else null end) > 0")
->count();
```

or shorter using `sum()`

```
DB::table('assigned_groups')
->where('username', $username)
->havingRaw("(sum(group_name ='A') > 0 and sum(group_name = 'B') > 0) or sum(group_name = 'C') > 0")
->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return DB::table('assigned_groups')
    ->where('username', $username)
    ->andWhere(function($query) use ($groupAandB, $groupC) {
        $query->whereIn('group_name', $groupAandB)
              ->orWhereIn('group_name', $groupC);
    })
    ->count();
```

I actually am not sure if there's an `orWhereIn` method, but this structure should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

$users = DB::select("select count(*) from user where username='$username'  and (username in (select username from user where group_name in ('A','B') having count(*) >1 group by username) or group_name ='C')");