# MySql list all fields having sum > 0

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

Some time ago I had a question how to write an sql query with multiple `count()`, [and got needed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331835/write-custom-sql-query-for-multiple-counts/).

Now let's say I have the exact same table

```
ID|group_name|username
----------------------
1 |    A     | user1
----------------------
2 |    B     | user2
----------------------
3 |    C     | user1

...
```

And the exact same query:

```
select count(*) from TABLE 
where username='user1'
having (sum(group_name ='A') > 0
     and sum(group_name = 'B') > 0)
     or sum(group_name = 'C') > 0")
```

But now I want not to count, but to **list all the usernames** that correspond to this `having` statement. That is, list all the usernames **that are in both A and B, or in C** group.

For now I've only tried only replacing `count(*)` with `username` and adding `group by username` at the and of my query, like this:

```
select username where username='user1' having (sum(group_name ='A') > 0 and sum(group_name = 'B') > 0) or sum(group_name = 'C') > 0") group by username
```

But I get syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY `username` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: If you get an syntax error, add the Statement and the error message here to get help on it

Comment: `HAVING` has to come ***after*** a `GROUP BY`, not ***before***...  And you also appear to be missing a `FROM yourTable`...

Comment: @MatBailie yep, that did the thing, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not adding Table Name here and also, you need to use group by before having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list username who satisfy your criteria you can write query as

```
select username
from table
group by username
having (
    sum(group_name ='A') > 0 and sum(group_name = 'B') > 0
) or sum(group_name = 'C') > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate by username and move your `WHERE` logic into a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT username
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY username
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN group_name NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 OR
    SUM(CASE WHEN group_name NOT IN ('C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Note that your current `WHERE` logic does not actually agree with what you wrote, if you really want users who are exclusively A/B or C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query to get `username`s which match the given criteria:

```
select username from users having (count(group_name ='A') > 0 and count(group_name = 'B') > 0) or count(group_name = 'C') > 0;
```

We try to get `username`s from `users` which have entries for both `group_name`s `A` and `B`, or have an entry for `group_name` `C`.

Hope this helps.